# Javascript replacing tab char with html unicode for JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-10

In IE10, to parse a JSON string which contains tab char it needs to be in unicode

for example:

```
jsonString="{\"mynameproperty\":\"Chetan    Shettigar\"}"
```

Parsing of above string fails in IE10 because there is a tab char `"Chetan Shettiga"`

The acceptable char string `Chetan&#9;Shettigar`

I am looking for a solution which can replace tab to respective html unicode.
May be a regular expression can solve this problem, but is there any other easy way?

Comment: `\t` should be used in json, for a tab. &#9 is html-encoded, which has NOTHING to do with json.

Comment: Both javascript string literals and JSON string literals work fine with plain tabs, no need to escape them. What error do you get?

Comment: I have tried using "Chetan\tShettigar", it is still failing.

Comment: @Bergi: I am getting Invalid character error message.. In IE8 it works without using html encoding for tab or newline, but in IE10 its not the same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

To replace all tabs with the html char code `&#9;`, you can use the `replace()` function, like this:

```
jsonString="{\"mynameproperty\":\"Chetan    Shettigar\"}".replace(/\t/g, '&#9;');
```

Although as mentioned in the comments, you should be using `\t` instead of html char codes, like this:

```
jsonString="{\"mynameproperty\":\"Chetan    Shettigar\"}".replace(/\t/g, '\\t');
```

Comment: thanks for answer. In IE10, \t cannot be used. tried it and getting invalid character error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jsonString="{\"mynameproperty\":\"Chetan    Shettigar\"}";
jsonString = jsonString.replace(/\t/g, "\\t");
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
document.body.innerHTML = obj.mynameproperty;
```

[DEMO in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLyER/)